# Не работает алгоритм?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, сортировка

делаю алгоритм сортировки на джаваскрипт. Работает на другом алгоритме - поиска наименьшего числа. Скрипт должен выводить массив от наименьшего до наибольшего числа но выводит наименьшее число подряд.

```js
function find_smallest(arr) {
  var smallest = arr[0];
  var smallest_index = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < smallest) {
      smallest = arr[i];
      smallest_index = i;
    }
  }
  
  return smallest;
}

function selection_sort(new_arr) {
  new_arr_2 = [];
  for (var n = 0; n < new_arr.length; n++) {
    new_arr_2.push(find_smallest(new_arr));
  }
  
  return new_arr_2;
}

console.log(selection_sort([90, 3, 5, 8, 90, 14, 90009]))
```

Comment: [Отладка в браузере Chrome](https://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Причина такого поведения в том, что на каждом шаге выполняется одно и то же - поиск минимального элемента в одном и тоже, не изменяющемся массиве `new_arr`

Для исправления нужно исключать найденный минимум из следующего поиска. Это можно сделать, например, удаляя соответствующий элемент (splice).

А можно выполнять поиск, начиная с n-го элемента на n-м шаге, и переставив минимум в начало (поменяв его с n-м). В результате второй массив не понадобится, и получится классическая сортировка выбором.

Answer (score 1):

В JS есть встроенная сортировка массивов, ничего выдумывать не нужно, это простейшая операция:

```
var numbers = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3];
numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
console.log(numbers); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort